# How to convert a jQuery one('click') event to load in the background on page load?

Tags: jquery

I've currently got this jquery triggered to the first click event of my select list.

When someone first clicks on the select list, the jQuery is fired and it takes a few seconds to complete and be ready for the user.

How can I change the function so that it operates in the background while (or as soon as) the page has loaded? I want it to be ready for the user before they click the select/pulldown menu (#my_select).

```
$('#my_select').one('click',function(){ 
        var myList = $(this);
        //myList.addClass("disabled");
        $('#my_select option').each(function(){
        var option = $(this);
        option.attr("disabled","disabled");
            $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/getStyle.php',{option: $(this).val()},function(response) 
            {
                if (response=='true'){option.attr("disabled","");}else{option.addClass("disabled");}
            });
        });
        //myList.attr("disabled","");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myList = $(this);myList.attr("disabled","disabled");
            $.get
            (
                '<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/getTemplates.php',function(response) 
                {
                    myList.attr("disabled","");
                }
            );

});
```

Use $(document).ready(); to execute script after the dom has fully loaded.

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty workaround as an alternative solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#my_select').trigger('click').unbind('click');
});
```

That will trigger the click event for #my_select once the page loads and then unbind the event so it doesn't happen when someone actually 'click's' it.

The proper way is to put the whole thing in a doc.ready as a standalone function rather than on an event.

Comment: Thanks Trebor. I'm noticing that the page appears to be stalling a bit before anything loads. Is there a way to delay the action a bit in order to make sure it does not proceed until a few seconds after the page has fully loaded?

Comment: change $(document).ready to $(window).load and see if that helps.